# How to avoid a Drupal7 view to show the results at startup?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Drupal7 View with 4 exposed filters.
It runs fine but i would like the results to be shown only when the user clicks the submit button and not when the view is loaded? How can i avoid this?

Comment: Try using the global null in arguments

Answer (score 2):

This behavior was recently included into views 3. You can select: Exposed Form Style: Input Required.

Answer (score 0):

Make on of the filters required and don't set a default value. The view will not return any results until the user selects something in that field.